# How would I go about finding stall/loiter speed data?

Tags: aircraft-performance, stall

I have a list of 6 fixed-wing and 2 tilt-rotor aircraft that I require the stall and loiter speeds for, however I have great trouble finding these. Is there a book or website that has an extensive list of aircraft and these kinds of statistics, or a method of calculating stall speeds?

Preferably your suggestions could be used in an science paper or cited directly. But any suggestion is welcome at this point.

If you are interested the list of aircraft are:
Leonardo:        AW609;
BellBoeing:      V-22 Osprey;
Beechcraft:      King Air B200;
Piper:           PA-31;
Lockheed Martin: HC-130J;
Airbus Military: HC-144;
Airbus:          CC-295;
Lockheed Martin: CC-130H;

Comment: No airplane has one single stall speed. It depends on configuration, load, etc. You can find various stall speeds in the PoH or on placards in the cockpit itself (at a minimum, you'll find the clean configuration at max gross weight stall speed, and the flaps-down at max gross weight stall speed). There's no such thing as "loiter speed", you can circle a point at any speed between stall speed and Vne. Perhaps you meant best endurance speed? Some airplanes may have that in their PoH as well, but it's not required.

Comment: With some care you might find pilot handbooks of these aircraft. Even for military machines (e.g. Ah-64 apache) have I seen these published. However the aw609 for example is so new, that you might have trouble finding such numbers